# Making recvfrom() function non-blocking

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, network-programming, udp

I am working on a UDP server/client application.

For finding out if any of the client is down, the server sends a handshake message to the client. Then, the server waits for the response of client to send some data to assure that the client is active. For this the server blocks in call to `recvfrom()` unless the client replies back, but if the client is down, the server blocks infinitely in call to `recvfrom()`.

I want to implement such a functionality on my server so that it waits in the call to `recvfrom()` for a specific time (say 2 secs). If no data was received from the client within 2 seconds, the client is considered to be dead and `recvfrom()` returns.

Is there any way to do it? I searched internet but found solutions like setting `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag that returns immediately when no data received, but in my case, I don't want `recvfrom()` to return immediately but wait for data for a specific duration of time, and when no data received for that specific duration, the `recvfrom()` function should return.

Comment: Ok you wants to implement reliable  service. you can set [recvfrom() function](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r11.hala001/rcvf.htm) in blocking mode, using  [fcntl() or ioctl() function](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r11.hala001/rcvf.htm). Also read this [UDP reliable data service implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353970/udp-reliable-data-service-implementation)

Comment: checkout **[c - Set timeout for winsock recvfrom - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824465/set-timeout-for-winsock-recvfrom)**

Comment: also [check out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .it gives you clear explanation in **WSARecv()** (has blocking rules for function).

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan It's ioctlsocket, for Windows. Somewhat lame and non-Unix-like, but sockets aren't treated as regular files...

Comment: @modifiablelvalue ok I didn't notice `window` tag. Anyway @ Ayesha There must be some similar way in windows also. Sorry I can't help on this more...Good Luck

Comment: What about using `select()` after having written to the client to be tested. `select()` takes on optional time-out.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all the helpful posts :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use `setsockopt()` to set a receive time-out for the socket in question.

`SO_RCVTIMEO` is used for this.

If a time-out has been set for a socket passed to `recvfrom()`, the function returns after this time-out if no data had been received.

For instance, to set a 10 μs read time-out (add error-checking on the value returned by `setsockopt()` as necessary):

```
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>

...

struct timeval read_timeout;
read_timeout.tv_sec = 0;
read_timeout.tv_usec = 10;
setsockopt(socketfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &read_timeout, sizeof read_timeout);
```

For details [on Windows please see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [on Linux see here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html) and/or [here (POSIX)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setsockopt.3p.html).

Comment: or use `select()` to wait for the socket to enter a readable state within a timeout, THEN call `recvfrom()` only when the socket is actually readable indicating data is available for reading.

Comment: I second the use of `select`. You get far better control, and its easier to upscale to handling multiple sockets.

Comment: Isn't the ms docs stating that SO_RCVTIMEO should be given a DWORD? Why are you giving it a timeval struct

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention! The example for the solution above is for Linux. The same operation with the same constants are different in windows!! I have found a small hint in [stackoverflow: set-timeout-for-winsock-recvfrom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824465/set-timeout-for-winsock-recvfrom) after I have searched a while, NO error message, NO warning.
The solution for windows is:

```
DWORD read_timeout = rxTimeout_us/1000;  // it is milliseconds!
error = setsockopt(so.socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char const*)&read_timeout, sizeof read_timeout);
```

Comment: No, the solution for Windows is to use [asynchronous I/O](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/synchronous-and-asynchronous-i-o).

Comment: Sorry, my hint was related only to the setsockopt(...) arguments, not for the complete solution. I am working fine with the timeout on recvfrom() in windows.